# Access object in if statement C++

Tags: c++

I want to access an object created in 'if' statement? Should I do it with a pointer or reference, overloading operator, should i try do something with function which returns an object? I know there is way to return a pointer to an object created by function itself but i do not know how to do it? Basically I want to have access to methods of class "myClass" outside the 'if' statement.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class myClass
{
  int num=2;
public:
  int show()
{
  return num;
}

int main()
{
  int choice=0;
  cout << "Type a number";
  cin >> choice;
  if (choice > 0)
  {
    myClass object;
  }
    cout << object.show();
}
```

Comment: Then create the object outside the if statement. Why are you trying to create the object inside the if statement if you want to access it outside the if statement? Programming is hard enough without creating your own problems.

Comment: What if the if-branch is not taken?

Comment: What you are struggling with [is called scope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_(computer_science)). The object will not exist once it goes out of scope, so a pointer or reference to it is worthless.

Comment: It may seem the language is trying to obstruct your intentions coding but scope is a critical concept. It keeps your code from being littered with different names/objects. This is crucial to developing anything but the smallest of programs.

Comment: I've managed it out by creating object outside the 'if' and just deleting it when they are useless

Answer (score 2):

Anything you declare inside a scope, which in this case is the 'true' branch of the 'if' statement, is local to that scope and is inaccessible (and is destroyed) when control leaves that scope. So you can't access the object unless it is declared outside the scope.

The solution is this. First make sure your class has a default constructor that does something sensible and another function that does whatever initialisation you need to do inside the 'if' statement. Like this:

```
class MyClass
    {
    public:
    MyClass();
    void Construct();
    void Show();

    private:
    // ...
    };

int main()
    {
    // ...

    MyClass object;
    if (choice)
        {
        object.Construct();
        }
    object.Show(); // this works because 'object' was created outside 'if'
    }
```